# How to pass EvoSuite parameters when using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, evosuite

When generating tests cases with Evosuite we can pass parameters several parameters, e.g.:

```
$ java -jar evosuite-1.0.6.jar -listParameters
...
sandbox              boolean        true               Execute tests in a sandbox environment
sandbox_mode         SandboxMode    RECOMMENDED        Mode in which the sandbox is applied (Values: [OFF, RECOMMENDED
...
```

Normally those parameters are passed simply by `-D<param>=<value>`.
However for my project I'm using Maven and not invoking Evosuite direclty from the command line.

I tried `mvn -D<param>=<value>` but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea on how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking at parameters which will be used to generate unit tests using maven:
I use below maven command for me to generate and test

```
mvn clean compile -DmemoryInMB=2000 -Dcores=4 -DtimeInMinutesPerClass=10 evosuite:generate test
```

Above command should be able to generate the tests and execute.

You can refer to this article if you need more information on the Evosuite with Maven http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/maven-plugin/